# Laravel - Download specified list of images from S3 into a directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I have been searching around but cannot find any information.

Currently have a list of images on my page and each have a download button which is just an a tag with the href of the image and the download attribute.

The client however would like to be able to download all images. Any suggestions?

Im using Vue + Laravel 5 so it can be API based etc if easier.

The aim is a download button that when clicked will allow me to specify a list of image names / urls in a bucket and then download them into a folder with a specific name.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider downloading the images on the server from S3 in a temporary folder. Then you could zip that folder and provide a response to the client with the appropriate header information to start the download.

Comment: You would want to delete the temporary folder and zip after the download. Or you could just overwrite it on the next iteration of this process.